# How to set cookies in an electron webview?

Tags: javascript, cookies, webview, electron

When retrieving cookies from an Electron WebView using [cookies.get](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/cookies.md#cookiesgetfilter-callback), I get an array of [cookie object](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/structures/cookie.md)s. So far so good. But when I try to set them back with [cookie.set](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/cookies.md#cookiessetdetails-callback), it is expecting an URL:

```
url String - The url to associate the cookie with.
```

which is not exported by get. This is on top of domain and path. How am I supposed to set the cookies again? Why is it even asking for a URL, aren't cookies associated by domain and path instead of a URL?

When I try to set them I get the very useful error of "Error: Setting cookie failed" and I'm just guessing it's the missing non-optional URL attribute.

Comment: I used the last time a workaround with this package https://github.com/hstove/electron-cookies

Comment: @Linucs: that doesn't offer an API to get and set cookies, does it?

Answer (score 1):

Add a `url` variable to your cookie with the domain of the site whose belong the cookie:

```
cookie.url = "http://example.com/";
```